# Network bandwith monitoring per users

Tags: firewall, monitoring, openwrt, hotspot

Please show me a fully open-source solution in this situation:

- Small network with about 30 pc with wireless cards.
- An Regular Asus wireless access-point which connected to the server.
- Server is a normal x86 PC with Ubuntu Linux. Server connects to Internet by ADSL.
- I want to monitor the traffic (visited sites & urls) and bandwidth (total size of download data per weak) of all users.

  - monitoring should done per USER (maybe by user-name in vpn connection) or MAC ID (because just specified network cards can connect to AP. each user has its own mac address)
  - not limiting the quota or traffic shaping or QoS. Just monitoring, even not real-time.

I do little search and I see some firewalls, such as Untangle, ... or things like OpenWRT.
I can buy a cheap wireless router (such as Asus N10+ which compatible by open-wrt). but its not preferred.

In my case, what is the best fully open-source solution?

Comment: -1 I suggest you do more than a little search.

Comment: In Super User, and all the StackExchange sites, shopping or product recommendations are considered off topic and open ended, and sometimes even too localized. Try to reword your question in a way that you are not asking for products, but more of processes; this will help keep it on topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can installl a proxy server like [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/Intro/) and use a report analyzer [SARG](http://sarg.sourceforge.net/) or [manageengine](http://www.manageengine.com/products/firewall/squid-proxy-report.html). You can find more analyzers in [this serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/23047/what-is-a-good-squid-logs-analyzer).

To monitor use per user, you will need to make them authenticate to squid and not use a transparent proxy or you will get only global use.

With a proxy on your server, you will be able to monitor but also to restrict the access to specific sites or words if needed. You have a lot of options to block per user, time or IP for example.

Comment: Thanks. but i want to preserve all the ports OPEN. squid just pass http(80) port, not ssh,smtp,...

Comment: On your firewall, you redirect only port 80 to squid and let the other ports without redirecting so they won't be affected by squid.

Comment: but squid need authentication. and each program (firefox, git,...) need to enter the user-name & password. I dont like it. it's preferred to enter them once(e.g by vpn connection) and all the apps use the connection.

Comment: I think you should read a little more on squid (or other proxy server) and you probably will be able to do what you want. For example, if your users use always the same computer, you can use squid transparent proxy (no login needed), fix the IPs in DHCP (should be possible because you say each user has one MAC ID authorized) and monitor the IPs (transparent mode can't monitor users as they are not logged in but can monitor IPs). Anyways, I don't believe you will be able to do that from a VPN login alone.